# Testing multiple classes with the same rspec tests

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm building a web app in ruby, and it does all of it's data access through repositories. To make my unit tests fast, I also have in-memory versions of these repositories.

I would like the behaviour of these repositories to be identical, so it makes sense to use the same tests for both the real and in-memory repositories.

How would I go about doing this?